# how to gracefully handle C callbacks from C++ code?

Tags: c++, c

I'm using a C library where the user is supposed to register a `int (*functionPtr)(int,int);` callback. 
Then, some file is processed, and during the file processing the user receives callback with the previously given function, up to thousands for a single file processing.

My question is, how to manage state for this kind of worflow?

For instance I'd like to count how many times the callback was called. The only way I'm thinking of doing this is :

```
int c = 0; //global variable
int callback(int i, int j) {
++c;
}
```

Which is basically not very pretty and forces me to manage global variables.

Is there a way to do this effeciently in C++ ? In my case I do *not* have access to C++11

Comment: A good C API provides callbacks of the form `int(*functionPtr)(void*, int, int)`, and asks for both the function pointer and a `void*`.  Look around for such a callback API, possibly in an "Ex" or "advanced" interface, or the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way is to support a context pointer:

```
void myAPI(void (*f)(void *, int, int), void *context) {
   ...
   // Call the callback passing the provided context
   f(context, x, y);
   ...
}
```

The users can then recover custom data from the context if needed... for example

```
void inc_counter(void *context, int x, int y) {
    *((int *)context) += 1;
}

void foo() {
    int count = 0;
    myAPI(inc_counter, &count);
}
```

In other words the idea is to add an opaque `void *` parameter to the callback interface and also a `void *` value to pass in that parameter when invoking the function.

This doesn't add any coupling but works around the problem that C has no closures.